# My app cashes after being idle for some time

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I got an application that shows a list of events. The data for the list is collected from an `api`, and i use a `asynctask` to get this data. It all workes fine, but for some reason the application crashes after a long time of idle(several hours). At the fragment that shows when i re-enter the application contains of a logo and a `listview`. The logo is showing but the `listview` is gone, and short after the app crashes. 
The problem is that i can't check the error with debugging. For some reason the error wont occur when it's in debug-mode.

Any ideas on what could cause the crash?
Before you set duplicate, i have checked out the other post, but their problems is not the same as mine.

The **scrollDisabledListview** i use:

```
public class ScrollDisabledListView extends ListView {

private int mPosition;

public ScrollDisabledListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ScrollDisabledListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ScrollDisabledListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    final int actionMasked = ev.getActionMasked() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;

    if (actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // Record the position the list the touch landed on
        mPosition = pointToPosition((int) ev.getX(), (int) ev.getY());
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    if (actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        // Ignore move events
        return true;
    }

    if (actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        // Check if we are still within the same view
        if (pointToPosition((int) ev.getX(), (int) ev.getY()) == mPosition) {
            super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        } else {
            // Clear pressed state, cancel the action
            setPressed(false);
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
 }
}
```

**The asynctask:**

```
private static class loginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>{
    private WeakReference<RingbillettFragmentActivity> activityWeakReference;

    loginTask(RingbillettFragmentActivity activity){
        activityWeakReference = new WeakReference<RingbillettFragmentActivity>(activity);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        RingbillettFragmentActivity activity = activityWeakReference.get();

        if(activity == null || activity.isFinishing()){
            return;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> myParams;
        JSONObject myJSON = null;
        boolean checkLogin = true;
        RingbillettFragmentActivity activity = activityWeakReference.get();
        if(activity == null || activity.isFinishing()){
            return false;
        }

        try {

            myParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            myParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", RingbillettUtils.hentToken(activity.getApplicationContext())));

            myJSON = RingbillettUtils.getJSONfromWebservice("validateToken", myParams);

            if (myJSON.getBoolean("TokenValid")) {
                activity.doLog("TokenValid = true");
                checkLogin = true;
            } else {

                activity.doLog("TokenValid = false");

                String OS = "Android";
                Integer OS_ver = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

                myParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("b", RingbillettUtils.hentLagretBrukernavn(activity.getApplicationContext())));
                myParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p", RingbillettUtils.hentLagretPassord(activity.getApplicationContext())));
                myParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("OS", OS));
                myParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("OS_ver", Integer.toString(OS_ver)));

                myJSON = RingbillettUtils.getJSONfromWebservice("DoLogin", myParams);

                if (myJSON.getBoolean("godkjent")) {

                    activity.doLog("DoLogin = godkjent");

                    String nyToken = myJSON.getString("token");
                    RingbillettUtils.lagreToken(activity.getApplicationContext(), nyToken);

                    checkLogin = true;
                } else {

                    activity.doLog("DoLogin = IKKE godkjent");

                    RingbillettUtils.lagreToken(activity.getApplicationContext(), null);
                    checkLogin = false;
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            activity.doLog("Exception : " + ex.getMessage());
            checkLogin = false;
        }

        return checkLogin;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        RingbillettFragmentActivity activity = activityWeakReference.get();
        if(activity == null || activity.isFinishing()){
            return;
        }

        if (result) {
            activity.doLog("BRUKER INNLOGGET");

        } else {
            activity.doLog("BRUKER IKKE INNLOGGET");
            RingbillettUtils.lagreToken(activity.context, null);
            RingbillettUtils.lagrePassord(activity.context, null);
            RingbillettUtils.lagreHuskPassord(activity.context, false);
            activity.brukernavn = RingbillettUtils.ANONYM;
            activity.brukerInnlogget = false;


        }

    }

}
```

**Programmatically setting the height of the listview**

```
if(adapter != null){
        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = adapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (adapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();

    }
```

Comment: Can you post crash logs?

Comment: also post the logcat here

Comment: i wish i could, but the app does not crash when it's in 'run' or 'debug'.

Comment: it only crashes when running it directly from my phone @quicklearner

Comment: can you add crashlytics in it :)

Comment: there are hundreds of ways to get the stacktrace from the non-debuggable app. Use one of them.

Comment: I'll install it and try @quicklearner :)